# onclick double paragraph elements number

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events, dom-events

I have 12 paragraphs, what I need to do is when I click on it, The text has to be doubled (double the elements), basically the number of rows has to be doubled, the thing is that when paragraph has 1000 elements, it can't be doubled anymore. Okay, so I have my html code here:

```
<div id="pastraipos">
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>it is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted.</p>
<p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available.</p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
<p>is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
</div>
```

So what I understand I need events in this, and loop that event listener, so I can have same effect on all paragraphs.

```
var lala = document.getElementById('pastraipos');
var lala1 = lala.childElementCount;

function F2(){
    for (i = 0; i < lala1; i++){
    var cln = lala.children[i].cloneNode(true);
    lala.appendChild(cln)[i+1];
  }
}

for (var k = 0; k < lala1; k++) {
            lala.children[k].addEventListener('click', F2, false);
}
```

The problem that it doubles all paragraphs, and can't figure out when paragraph has 1000 elements in it (space counts).

Comment: 1000 elements means paragraph string length

Comment: So if i need to double it, first i need to check if string length * 2 <= 1000?
And if yes, where i do this check in function or where I run event listener?

Comment: Put that check inside F2